# rails callbacks and order or events

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, sidekiq

I have three different API calls happening when a record is created.

1) Call to create a bitly URL for the record.
2) Call to post to facebook with the bitly URL
3) Call to post to twitter with the bitly URL

My current process is as follows:

On record Create and Update

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @dealer.save
    call_bitly_api
  end
end
```

in my model:

```
after_save :social_media_posting

def social_media_posting
  if (self.bitly_url.present? && self.posted_to_facebook == false)
    call_facebook_post
  end
  if (self.bitly_url.present? && self.posted_to_twitter == false)
    call_twitter_post
  end
end
```

The issue that I am facing is that the facebook and twitter post is being called on first save where the bitly_url is not yet created.

Need help is figuring out how to add these calls that they can still happen yet they happen in order and wait for the bitly_url to be present before the call the facebook and twitter is made? Major thing worth mentioning I am using sidekiq to make the calls and send the actual call to the sidekiq worker to work in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller:

```
CallBitlyWorker.perform_async(dealer.id)
```

In your worker:

```
class CallBitlyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(dealer_id)
    dealer = Dealer.find(dealer_id)
    # make bitly call
    dealer.update_attribute(:bitly_url, some_url)

    # make the social media calls in parallel
    CallFacebook.perform_async(dealer_id)
    CallTwitter.perform_async(dealer_id)
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord callbacks should be avoided where possible.  They just make your code more opaque.

Comment: If the sidekiq worker fails for whatsoever reason, will it not call the facebook and twitter postings again and again?

Comment: Depends on how you write the job.

Comment: Following exactly how you suggested. So far seems to be working. Thanks for the assistance.